# Add more database records to the text-box in Navision 2009

Tags: navision

I have a text-box with the `name:txtShowMoreDetails`. And I want to show more then one table record in it. I try it like this:

```
 LocLocationtClientMethod.City        := FORMAT(CurrForm.txtShowMoreDetails);
 LocLocationtClientMethod."Post Code" := FORMAT(CurrForm.txtShowMoreDetails);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way around...define a Global Text Variable called txtShowMoreDetails (for example) and in the OnAfterGetRecord trigger of the Form populate the variable with those fields from the database:

```
txtShowMoreDetails := LocLocationtClientMethod.City + ' ' + LocLocationtClientMethod."Post Code";
```

don't forget to set the TextBox to Editable=No on the Form

Cheers!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!